# Why System.Delegate can not be used as event?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

## Main Question

```
event System.Delegate d;
```

Code above will raise error:

> Compiler Error CS0066
> 'event': event must be of a delegate type

Why System.Delegate can not be used as event?
If I want an event to accept any kind of delegate, what should I use?

---

## Afterwards

(Added one week later.  Below is not very related to the question.  It is more about my own problem.)

Thanks to @John.
Thanks about his answer. And thanks about asking me "Why would you want such a thing?".

I said "If I need an event, but I'm not sure what kind of method I may use in the event. Then I would want to have an event for any kind."
The situation in my mind is something like below:
There is a complicated class like Enviroment, changing from different part of it may raise different kinds of event.

```
class Environment
{
    float temperature;
    float humidity;
    float factor3;
    float factor4;
    float factor5;
    //more factors may be added later.
}

/*
    Need an event for Environment.
    The event should invoke: 
        TemperatureInfluence.OnTemperatureChange(...)
        HumidityInfluence.OnHumidityChange(...)
        Factor3And4Influence.OnFactor3And4Change(...)
        Factor4And5Influence.OnFactor4And5Change(...)
    and it should be albe to handle mehtod of new kinds.
*/

class TemperatureInfluence
{
    public void OnTemperatureChange(float temperature)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Temperature changed, put on more or less clothes");
    }
}

class HumidityInfluence
{
    public void OnHumidityChange(float humidity)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Humidity changed, drink more or less water");
    }
}

class Factor3And4Influence
{
    public void OnFactor3And4Change(float factor3, float factor4)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Factor3 and Factor4 changed, do blablabla");
    }
}

class Factor4And5Influence
{
    public void OnFactor4And5Change(float factor4, float factor5)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Factor4 and Factor5 changed, do hohohuhu");
    }
}
```

I think my problem is that I didn't understand what event keyword is in C#.
The event keyword adds some features to delegate and that's it.(So it should be the same as delegate, with precise paramters.)
It is different from real word event, which can be of any kind.

If I really need an event of any kind, I should not count on event keyword. I think I may need to make a structure for this or just write new code for new event.

Comment: Why would you want such a thing?

Comment: I'm not sure if my situation is meaningless -- If I need an event, but I'm not sure what kind of method I may use in the event. Then I would want to have an event for any kind.

Comment: How could you not know what kind of method you may use? You're the one invoking it in your type so you have to know. I'm not sure that you properly understand how events work. I suggest that you read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html) for some clarity.

Comment: The purpose of events is to indicate that something happened. What is it that's happening in your type that you want to notify listeners about?

Comment: *I'm not sure what kind of method I may use in the event* - you need to decide what kind of method you will use in the event. It's not a complicated decision; how many arguments and what types

Comment: I'm learning delegate and event these days. It is true I don't properly understand how events work. And I think I basically understand event now. Thank you.

Comment: I added something to the question. If you have more suggestion to me, very welcome.

Comment: Remember that a Delegate is reference type, referencing a particular method.  An Event is "a special kind of delegate" where multiple consumes can be added to a subscribe list. Basically when the event is invoked, it contacts it's list of subscribers to invoke those implementations.  This is a little different from a method reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.Delegate` is a class, not a delegate.

An event is a member of a type. All members must have their own data type specified. You can use `Object` for fields and the like if you want to be able to refer to any type, or you can use a base type to refer to any derived type. Delegate types don't inherit each other so there's no base delegate type that you can specify to refer to derived delegate types.

It doesn't make sense anyway. Why would you want to accept delegates to methods with parameters that you have no way to pass arguments for? Just declare your event as type `EventHandler` and then you can pass the usual arguments, i.e. `object sender, EventArgs e` but methods with no parameters can still be used as handlers. Any other parameters make no sense as you can't provide arguments anyway.